# Object detection and geolocating the bounding boxes

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, gis

I have acquired videos from a dashcam installed on a vehicle that went around different portions of an airport. My objective is to detect cracks in the pavements. After identifying them, I then need to geolocate them, i.e., tell where the cracks appear in terms of lat/long.

So far, I have labeled a handful of images and used FasterRCNN to detect the cracks. I can perhaps use the centers of the bounding boxes around each identified crack to locate them. Since I'm not familiar enough with computer vision and what it can offer, I'm stuck at this stage of my work. I looked around at sources and materials such as monoSLAM and triangulation techniques, but they weren't easy to follow. Basically, I would need something like a mapping function that can relate the pixel values to lat/long.

I was hoping for a more straightforward solution or a better reference to understand my problem and hopefully be able to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  This question appears a little too open-ended to be a good fit for our format.  If you could identify a specific sub-problem that could be addressed within those limits (which you can read about in our [help]), we would be glad to help.

Comment: I have a dataset of dashcam images in an airport. The dashcam images are looking ahead and not down. I assume that the camera's orientation stays the same throughout the recording.  Let's say I use FasterRCNN to detect the cracks on the pavement and have the bounding boxes around each identified. Now I want to be able to geolocate or triangulate these cracks, given that I know the camera's GPS coordinates. I think there should be a method or a way that can do that, but I'm not familiar enough with CV and what it can offer. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Some questions like this have been fielded at [gis.se] -- that's worth a look.  It sounds more like a geometry problem than a statistical one, although I think you're correct in supposing that statistical thinking could be helpful.  But for it to be so, we would need to understand the nature and sources of error and variation in your data.